# Plot pie-chart in R

Tags: r, pie-chart

```
totalReads=10000
mappedReads=8000
mappedTargetReads=6000
unmappedReads=totalReads-mappedReads
offtargetmappedReads=mappedReads-mappedTargetReads
data<-c(mappedReads,unmappedReads,mappedTargetReads,offtargetmappedReads)
round(data[1]/totalReads*100)->a
round(data[2]/totalReads*100)->b
round(data[3]/mappedReads*100)->c
round(data[4]/mappedReads*100)->d
pct<-c(a,b,c,d)
labels<-c("MappedReads","UnmappedReads","On-exon","Off-exon")
labels<-paste(labels,pct)
labels<-paste(labels,"%", sep="")
pie(c(mappedReads,unmappedReads,mappedTargetReads,offtargetmappedReads),labels=labels)
```

Which basically plots all the four slices independently. But here `mappedTargetReads`, `offtargetmappedReads` are calculated with respect to mapped reads and therefore, I would like to subdivide the `mappedReads` slice and represent `mappedTargetReads`, `offtargetmappedReads` within `mappedReads`.

Or is it possible to plot two different piecharts next to each other in a single Rplot?

Comment: Do note that pie charts are a rather inefficient way of transmitting information. See e.g. http://blog.jgc.org/2009/08/please-dont-use-pie-charts.html.

Answer (score 2):

This produces a plot with two pie charts:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
pie(c(mappedReads,unmappedReads),labels=labels[1:2], main = "Global")
pie(c(mappedTargetReads,offtargetmappedReads),labels=labels[3:4],
    main = "MappedReads")
```

[image]